# Plotting a scatter plot with Spyder IDE

Tags: python

I'm following this Data Science Course and they don't explain the material well.
Could someone please explain the following to me?

In this Line:

```py
plt.annotate(label, xy= (friend_count, minute_count), xytext = (-5,5), textcoords = 'offset points')
```

What is the purpose of `xytext` argument? Why is it `(5,-5)`, what do the numbers represent?
What is `'offset points'` and its purpose?

Thank you!

Comment: `xytext`  is the position `(x,y)` to place the text at.

Comment: See the documentation for `matplotlib.pyplot.annotate` at https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html and an example of using the `xytext` argument to position the annotation text on the plot at https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/pyplots/annotation_basic.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-annotation-basic-py

Comment: Your link is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check out the documentation of [`matplotlib.pyplot.annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html):

**`xytext`** : is the position `(x,y)` to place the text at. If `None`, defaults to xy.

**`textcoords`** : The coordinate system that `xytext` is given in. `'offset points'`set the offset from the xy value in points.